# Setting navigationItem title

Tags: ios

In my app I am using storyboard, I need to change the title on a viewController. I am doing it as follows. In the .h file:

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
```

And in the .m file:

```
@synthesize categoriaDescription,navBar;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *category = self.categoriaDescription;

    NSLog(@"Value of category = %@", category);

    [self.navBar setTitle:category];

...
```

The default title is not changed, it should be 'A', the value of 'category' in this case. The Log shows 'A'.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use NavigationController?

realize that `viewController.navigationItem` does not have any sense if the viewController does not belongs to the navigationController's stack

Comment: Thank you, I know, but I don't want a navigationBar on the first viewController.

Comment: just hide it with   `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` in first view in `viewWillAppear` and show again with `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;` in `viewWillDisappear`. UPDATED. Use `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;`

Comment: I will try it, but I have a tabbarcontroller and five view controllers attached to it, where should I put the navigationcontroller?

Comment: each VC that needs a header should have it's own navController with relationship `root view controller` attached to the VC

Comment: If you will not, just use `Navigation Bar` object. It's a simple view which can be useful if you are not going to implement some real deep navigation in you tab page

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController setTitle:@"myTitle"];
```

This should work.

EDIT:
If you do not have a navController on your storyboard

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
[navController setTitle:@"myTitle"];

[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

Comment: Thank you, but your proposal is not working. I have used it before, but I am not using a navigationController in the storyBoard. This is the reason to declare the UINavigationItem in my .h file.

Comment: Thank you, it is not working as you posted. There is an error at 'rootViewController', I have changed it for 'self'. And in the last line, I have changed self.navigationController for navController, but the title isn't shown.

Comment: I made some changes to the code in my answer. Check if it works and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts, but it doesn't work either.